# Changes in backend not showing in front

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website example.com.

Right now I'm in the admin panel example.com/wp-admin

The admin panel is fine - I can see all of my pages int he back end.

But, when I visit the site (front) there is some holder page along the lines "Coming Soon a great website".

I do not know where this page is coming from. I never created it. I looked in my domain providers root folder and see just the wordpress files. I was looking to see if there was some default index.html file over riding things but could not see one.

Anyone recognize this issue or have any ideas?

Here is what the root directory looks like:
[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could post a link so we could evaluate this further. If you just created the website your domain might still be in propagation.

Answer (score 0):

most of the case this is because index.html or home.html Check the directory, where wordpress is installed, for mentioned file/s and if you see index.html or home.html, just rename it like ****.html~old

Comment: thanks for the tip but no file exists along those lines. I added a picture above of the root

Comment: Tried - no luck. Removed the file. What did change though was we now got an error 404 message. Same "theme" and background from default message. It seems the wordpress backend is not directing to the correct directory. I don't know where it's pointing

Comment: just noticed that it's not Linux server, but IIS, right? This may help http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS